# Perl XS garbage collection

Tags: perl, garbage-collection, perl-xs

I had to deal with a really old codebase in my company which had C++ apis exposed via perl.

In on of the code reviews, I suggested it was necessary to garbage collect memory which was being allocated in c++.

Here is the skeleton of the code:

```
char* convert_to_utf8(char *src, int length) {
    .
    .
    .
    length = get_utf8_length(src);
    char *dest = new char[length];
    .
    .
    // No delete
    return dest;
}
```

Perl xs definition:

```
PROTOTYPE: ENABLE

char * _xs_convert_to_utf8(src, length)
    char *src
    int length

CODE:
    RETVAL = convert_to_utf8(src, length)

OUTPUT:
    RETVAL
```

so, I had a comment that the memory created in the c++ function will not garbage collected by Perl. And 2 java developers think it will crash since perl will garbage collect the memory allocated by c++. I suggested the following code.

```
CLEANUP:
    delete[] RETVAL
```

Am I wrong here?

I also ran this code and showed them the increasing memory utilization, with and without the CLEANUP section. But, they are asking for exact documentation which proves it and I couldn't find it.

Perl Client:

```
use ExtUtils::testlib;
use test;

for (my $i=0; $i<100000000;$i++) {
    my $a = test::hello();
}
```

C++ code:

```
#define PERL_NO_GET_CONTEXT
#include "EXTERN.h"
#include "perl.h"
#include "XSUB.h"

#include "ppport.h"
#include <stdio.h>

char* create_mem() {
    char *foo = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*150);
    return foo;
}
```

XS code:

```
MODULE = test       PACKAGE = test      
    char * hello()
CODE:
    RETVAL = create_mem();
OUTPUT:
    RETVAL
CLEANUP:
    free(RETVAL);
```

Comment: Why do they think Perl would try to garbage collect the memory allocated by C++?    What exactly is the *it* you are asked to prove?

Comment: @ysth That perl would not garbage collect the memory allocated by C++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid that the people who wrote (and write) the Perl XS documentation probably consider it too obvious that Perl cannot magically detect memory allocation made in other languages (like C++) to document that explicitly. There's a bit in the [perlguts](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlguts.html#Memory-Allocation) documentation page that says that all memory to be used via the Perl XS API must use Perl's macros to do so that may help you argue.

Comment: Re "*that all memory to be used via the Perl XS API must use Perl's macros*", The OP's `mem` isn't such memory. That passage is referring to memory that Perl will need to deallocate. (For example, the buffer passed to `SvPV_set` must be allocted using Perl's allocator. However, `SvPV_set` is not something you'd normally use.) The OP's `mem` can safely be allocated by any allocator. (You'll need to use corresponding deallocator to free it as always.)

Answer (score 1):

When you write XS code, you're writing C (or sometimes C++) code. You still need to write proper C/C++, which includes deallocating allocated memory when appropriate.

---

The glue function you desire XS to create is the following:

```
void hello() {
    dSP;                       // Declare and init SP, the stack pointer used by mXPUSHs.
    char* mem = create_mem();
    mXPUSHs(newSVpv(mem, 0));  // Create a scalar, mortalize it, and push it on the stack.
    free(mem);                 // Free memory allocated by create_mem().
    XSRETURN(1);
}
```

`newSVpv` makes a copy of `mem` rather than taking possession of it, so the above clearly shows that `free(mem)` is needed to deallocate `mem`.

---

In XS, you could write that as

```
void hello()
CODE:
    {                          // A block is needed since we're declaring vars.
        char* mem = create_mem();
        mXPUSHs(newSVpv(mem, 0));
        free(mem);
        XSRETURN(1);
    }
```

Or you could take advantage of XS features such as `RETVAL` and `CLEANUP`.

```
SV* hello()
    char* mem;                 // We can get rid of the block by declaring vars here.
CODE:
    mem = create_mem();
    RETVAL = newSVpv(mem, 0);  // Values returned by SV* subs are automatically mortalized.
OUTPUT:
    RETVAL
CLEANUP:                       // Happens after RETVAL has been converted
    free(mem);                 //   and the converted value has been pushed onto the stack.
```

Or you could also take advantage of the typemap, which defines how to convert the returned value into a scalar.

```
char* hello()
CODE:
    RETVAL = create_mem();
OUTPUT:
    RETVAL
CLEANUP:
    free(RETVAL);
```

All three of these are perfectly acceptable.

---

A note on mortals.

Mortalizing is a delayed reference count decrement. If you were to decrement the `SV` created by `hello` before `hello` returns, it would get deallocated before `hello` returns. By mortalizing it instead, it won't be deallocated until the caller has a chance to inspect it or take possession of it (by increasing its reference count).